# temporarily seal leaky pipe under sink?

Tags: plumbing, repair

Going to the hardware store right now to fix this leak (see crack in pvc in the photos). My main question is: what's the best product to get to temporarily fix this so we can use the sink until the plumber comes tomorrow?

Second question: Is this completely manageable to fix myself? Would I have to cut the copper or something?

[image: here]
[image: here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice Pics.  For a good temp fix on this drain line, I'd recommend "Seals All". This avail at any hardware store.  As far as a permanent fix, you may not have to deal with the copper, but you will have to cut the PVC in an area where you can fit a coupling and replace the parts to the copper.  Thread on  the new adapter to the copper and use a PVC coupling to reconnect to the rest of the drain.  This will mean some cutting, primer and PVC cement.

Comment: Thanks. I just bought and applied some plumber's epoxy putty that will supposedly dry in 20 minutes. I'm hoping this thing will get me through until tomorrow. I've done small copper piping replacement before, as well as PVC drains. However, I'm not confident with the large copper-to-pvc thing this has.

Comment: once you cut the PVC, you should see that it simply threads off the copper.  Use some teflon tape on the threads when you reinstall the PVC threaded to glue coupling.